# Rails index controller find all or create records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an API where I am going to return `delivery_methods` for events. When an admin logs in to view the delivery methods screen (to edit descriptions, for example), the API request should return the delivery methods they've created or edited, but if non exist in the DB, some default ones should be generated.

Is this a good idea to drop into the `index` route of the controller? The API request would be something like `/api/delivery_methods`. Code would look something like:

```
def index
    @delivery_methods = DeliveryMethod.find_all_or_create_defaults(current_admin)
end
```

I haven't tested any code out, just asking for "best practice" opinions here. Thanks!

Comment: I think a better choice would be to use an after_create action on the admin model to set up those default delivery methods when the admin is first registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a GET route that modifies/creates resources is not considered a good practice.

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.
>   https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Generating default records should instead by done either by a seed file, rake task or as a model lifecycle callback if they need to be created at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was thinking, just thought I'd ask.